# Is there any way to check who approved or rejected my edit?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits

Can I check the people who reviewed my suggested edit? If yes, how?

Comment: Out of curiosity... why?

Comment: No reason, really. Just wanted to get an idea about the reputation of reviewers.

Comment: Anyone with [full editing privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) can also review suggested edits. So, that means anyone with 2k or more reputation. In addition, as in the case that Rob linked, the original author of an edited post can review suggested edits to that post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find it by visiting the revision history of the post. You can access this by clicking on the 'edited x minutes ago' link at the bottom of the post. You're then taken here:

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56625159/revisions

Then simply click the 'edit approved' hyperlink next to your revision:

[image]

For suggestions which were rejected, you'll need to find them via your [activity history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=suggestions)